# Is putting monorepo packages under a package folder a convention, or do yarn workspace expect that?

Tags: yarn-workspaces

My monorepo folder structure looks like this, but I haven't got cross app imports to work for yarn workspaces, that is, I can't import from `shared` to `app1` or `app2`.

```
./
  app1
  app2
  shared
  server
  package.json
```

Nearly all other workspaces I've seen includes a packages folder, is this required or just a convention? My folder structure would in that case look like:

```
./
  packages
    app1
    app2
    shared
    server
  package.json
```

Do I need to refactor for workspaces to work?

Answer (score 2):

It's just a convention. You need to list your `workspaces` in `package.json`:

```json
  "workspaces": [
    "app1",
    "app2",
    "shared",
    "server"
  ],
```

The convention let's you use a glob (and presumably streamlines some other `npm`/`yarn` commands that you want to run across all packages):

```json
  "workspaces": ["packages/*"],
```